# PHP Puttin values of array into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello I want to put values of single array into a multidimensional array with each value on a n+1 
This is my array $structures

```
Array
(
    [0] => S
    [1] => S.1
    [2] => S-VLA-S
    [3] => SB
    [4] => SB50
)
```

What I want for output is this

```
Array
(
[S] => Array(
    [S.1] => Array (
        [S-VLA-S] => Array (
            [SB] => Array (
                [SB50] => Array(
                    'more_attributes' => true
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
)
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
$structures = explode("\\", $row['structuurCode']);

foreach($structures as $index => $structure) {
    $result[$structure][$structure[$index+1]] = $row['structuurCode'];
}
```

The values of the array is a tree structure that's why it would be handy to have them in an multidimensional array

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More interestingly: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: And _perhaps_ just as interesting, what have you tried?

Comment: The values of the array is a tree structure. I tried by looping with foreach but no result

Comment: @JoachimVanthuyne At least you tried something.. Can you edit your original post and post the code you tried. (the loop you mentioned)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It becomes pretty trivial once you start turning it inside out and "wrap" the inner array into successive outer arrays:

```
$result = array_reduce(array_reverse($structures), function ($result, $key) {
    return [$key => $result];
}, ['more_attributes' => true]);
```

Obviously a more complex solution would be needed if you needed to set multiple paths on the same result array, but this is the simplest solution for a single path.

Comment: That is way better

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach:

```
    $var = array('a','an','asd','asdf');
    $var2 = array_reverse($var);
    $result = array('more_attributes' => true);
    $temp = array();
    foreach ($var2 as $val) {
        $temp[$val] = $result;
        $result = $temp;
        $temp = array();
    }
```